# Coop level difference catch up

Tags: torchlight-2

I've been playing for about 4-5 hours with a friend and he's levelled a full level above me.

Is there either any way to ensure we level equally or any way I can catch up with him without taking our quests out of sync, like farming mobs not related to quests or any mods that could help?

Comment: Also it may be worth getting some `+x% exp` gear to slowly even the odds if you find yourself falling behind repeatedly. The adventuring scroll can help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a LAN game and while setting it up click the re-roll world option. This will reset all areas for you to farm while keeping quest progress.

Comment: Should I do any of the lan quests also or just farm mobs?  Would doing quests effect my game with my coop over the internet?

Comment: Your quest progress is tracked on your character, not whether you play on/offline or LAN. I just suggest LAN because it is the only way to get the re-roll world option. Any quests you complete in LAN will be complete when you rejoin online co-op.

Comment: Ah sweet, so re-roll world on lan.  Will definitely do that.  Sorry to labour the point I just want to make 100% sure, as the quest progress is tracked on my computer, would doing quests on a re-roll world on lan still effect my online quest progress, even though on lan it's re-rolled?

Comment: Once you complete a quest it's done. Re-rolling only resets spawns and creates a new map and has no effect on quests or characters.